# Error with viewing an ionic HTML page after routing through Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I wrote a code for for my app, when a I click on the toggle to reach the second page, the url changes it took me there but nothing is appeared, just a blank page no more,

here is the app.js code

```
angular.module("BloodDonationApp", [
    "ionic",


])

.run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.keyboard.hidekeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
        if (window.statusBar) {
            //org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
            statusbar.styleDefault();
        }
    });
})
    //****************ROUTES***************//
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        abstarct: true,
        url: "/home",
        templateUrl: "templates/home.html"
    })

    .state('home.feeds', {
        url: "/feeds",
        views: {
            "tab-feeds": {
                templateUrl: "templates/feeds.html"
            }
        }
    })
   .state('home.settings', {
             url: "/settings",
             views: {
                 "tab-settings": {
                     templateUrl: "templates/settings.html"
                 }
             }
         })

    .state('requestDetails', {

        url: "/RequestDetails/:id",
        view: {
            "mainContent": {
                templateUrl: "templates/requestDetails.html"

            }
        }
    })
        .state('requestDetails.ClientRegister', {
            url: "/Client-Register/:id",
            view: {
                "mainContent": {
                    templateUrl: "templates/ClientRegister.html"
                }
            }
        });

    //if name of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home/feeds');
})
```

and here is the html code of the feeds page:

```
<ion-view ng-controller="FeedsCtrl as vm">
    <ion-content class="has-header">

        <div class="card" ng-repeat="requests in vm.feeds">
            <div class="item item divider" ng-click="toggleGroup(requests)"
                 ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(requests)}">
                <div class="row row-bottom">
                    <div class="col">
                        {{requests.type}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        {{requests.unitNb}} Units
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item-accordion"
                 ng-show="isGroupShown(requests)" ng-click="goToDetails()">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-top">
                        Since 7 s{{requests.Date}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col col-center col-50 col-offset-8">
                        <br/>{{requests.HospName}}
                        <br/>
                        {{requests.Hosplocation}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col col-bottom">
                        <a class="item item-icon-right">
                            <div class="row">
                                <i class="ion-icon ion-pinpoint "></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                {{requests.HospDistance}}4km
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

and the controller for feeds:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('BloodDonationApp')
        .controller('FeedsCtrl', ['BloodDonationApi', '$scope', '$state', FeedsCtrl]);

    function FeedsCtrl(BloodDonationApi, $scope, $state) {
        var vm = this;
        //start Data Binding functions//
        var data = BloodDonationApi.getRequests();
        console.log(data);
        vm.feeds = data;
        //end Data Binding//



        //start Accordion function//

        $scope.toggleGroup = function (requests) {
            if ($scope.isGroupShown(requests)) {
                $scope.shownGroup = null;
            } else {
                $scope.shownGroup = requests;
            }

        }

        $scope.isGroupShown = function (requests) {
            return $scope.shownGroup === requests;
        }
        $scope.goToDetails = function() {
            $state.go('requestDetails', {id : 5});
        }


        //end Accordion function//

    };
})();
```

but the request details is not appeared after clicking on the toggle its just give a blanck page, the html code :

```
<ion-view ng-controller="RequestDetailsCtrl as vm">
    <ion-content class="has-header">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        {{requests.type}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        {{requests.unitNb}} Units
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        {{requests.HospName}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        {{requests.Hosplocation}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        4 Km Away
                    </div>
                </div>

                <button class="button button-block button-positive">
                    Yes, I donate <i class="ion-icon ion-thumbsup"></i>
                </button>
                <label>
                    4/5 <i class="ion-icon ion-battery-half"></i>
                </label>
                <div class="title">
                    <h3>
                        Last time I'd donated was since<br /> 4 months
                        <i class="ion-icon ion-checkmark-round"></i>
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

the controller:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('BloodDonationApp')
        .controller('RequestDetailsCtrl', ['BloodDonationApi', '$stateParams', '$scope', RequestDetailsCtrl]);

    function RequestDetailsCtrl(BloodDonationApi, $stateParams, $scope) {
        var vm = this;
        var data = BloodDonationApi.getRequests();
        console.log(data);
        vm.requestDetails = data;
        console.log("$stateParams", $stateParams.id);      
        //end Data Binding//
        //  Get you request
    };
})();
```

am sure that there is an error with the view code, but m not figuring it out, if anybody can help me plz.

Comment: can you make a plnkr?

Comment: no I don't use it, if u want I can give u the git link to download it

Comment: ok, please give me a link

Comment: ok I download it already

Comment: okk, thnk u waiting for u if u could help me plz

Comment: right, can you point it which part is not working as require for me plz?

Comment: in the feeds page, when clicking on the second part of the toggle it must take me to request details page, but the view of this page is not appeared it just a blank page, while the url is changing with no view for the page

Comment: in second part of the toggle - you mean where you got 4km ? my url is not changing at all ?

Comment: yea this part of the toggle where is a brief details of the request, ohhh yea wait wait I forget to commit the changes to link just a second

Comment: lol, that explain why I couldn't see it

Comment: yea now download it again if u plz a pushed the changes m sry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inside a nested state when you are tying to load requestDetails so change your state to :

```
  .state('requestDetails', {...})

  .state('home.requestDetails', {
      url: "/feeds/:id",
      views: {
        'tab-feeds' :{
          templateUrl: "templates/requestDetails.html"
        }
      }
    })
```

and your method to:

```
$scope.goToDetails = function() {
        $state.go('home.requestDetails', {id : 5});
    }
```

and It's working !

I've fork your git so updated working version is here if you want to [pull](https://github.com/macrog/BloodDonationSystem)

Comment: I don't know how to pull it with the changes u fork for, u mean here that I change the feeds state to this ? I didn't understand the requestdetails state u wrote with {...}

Comment: check your github, not sure how can I update your master but I think you need to accept my commit

Comment: yea yea done it works thnk u a lot dude... but ididnt understand why it need this if u can explain it, or if u have a reference ?

Comment: please have a look in this [page](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/nested-states-&-nested-views) about nested states, but basically ui-router need ui-view to render the view, while your feeds it's already a child state to home you were trying to show a requestDetails from feeds you need ui-view to display it, easiest way it's to re-use the feeds tab to show it there :) Happy to help. Let me know if you need any more help with it ?

Comment: alright then, m really glad for that, thank u again, if I can have ur email  thus I can ask u whenever I need some help ??